# How to use Ç,Ü,İ characters on Code 128 in ZebraDesigner

Tags: character, barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, code128

How to use Ç,Ü,İ characters on Code 28 in ZebraDesigner ? if i use the letter İ or Ç on the barcode, it doesn't work .. Is it possible that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly it is only possible to use **standard ASCII** characters in Code 128 command `^BC`. Alltough you can use three different character subsets (Subset A, Subset B and Subset C) neither contains the characters you need!

For more details please refer to the [official documentation](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) of the `^BC` ZPL command.